# messages.array is not a function in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this worked which worked fine for v12 of discord.js , but doesn't work in v13. Any ideas? This is a part of code, everything is closed later on.

```
 interaction.channel.messages.fetch().then(async messages => {

      let finalArray = [];

      const putInArray = async (data) => finalArray.push(data);
      const handleTime = (timestamp) => moment(timestamp).format(`DD/MM/YYYY - hh:mm:ss a`).replace("pm", "PM").replace("am", "AM");

      for (const message of messages.array().reverse()) await putInArray(`${handleTime(message.createdTimestamp)} ${message.author.tag}: ${message.content}`);
```

Solution from https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManagerscrollTo=fetch
not working

Answer (score -2):

messages is already an array so you don't need to call the messages.array() function, see https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch

Comment: It clearly states there that it returns a Message, or a Collection of Messages. It never says anything about returning an array